# 301 .htacess redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm making a website, (for examples sake it will be http://www.example.com).
I am trying to make it redirect http://example.com/jquery/releasenotes to http://blog.jquery.com/?s=release+notes
By using this it put a `/` on the end, this stops it from working, since it searches for the `/` aswell. I tried using  http://goo.gl and converted it to http://goo.gl/WdiItL Somehow this also fails to remove the `/` when in redirect. However if you simply go to http://goo.gl/WdiItL it works. My .htaccess file looks like this:

`Redirect 301 /jquery/releasenotes http://goo.gl/WdiItL`

I have no idea how to make it not have the `/` on the end.
Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/jquery/releasenotes/?$ http://goo.gl/WdiItL
```

**Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use mod_rewrite's %{QUERY_STRING}

**for example:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(par1=1&par2=2)
RewriteRule ^$ http://alt.example.com/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have tried that, and tried editing it a bit, but still the `/` gets thrown on the end. :/